# RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY

Tags: plsql, rank

I need to rank by several columns;

```
ORDER_SEQ = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ORDER_ID, A.ORDER_NAME, A.START_DT_TM ORDER BY A.START_DT_TM)
```

The problem is that I need the third argument in the partition to be by the date only and not the datetime.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TRUNC to truncate the date.

```
TRUNC(a.start_dt_tm,'dd')
```